# Tap to click in plasma

Tags: kubuntu, 19.04, plasma-5

How to configure tap to click in plasma after default kubuntu installation? Which packages provide this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open system settings and under the hardware section go to input devices and select touchpad, then enable tap to click and apply setting
[Visual aid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dawrq.png)

[image: Touchpad settings]

Answer (score 2):

In the KDE Plasma Settings menu under `Desktop Behavior > Workspace`, you will see the options under `Click Behavior`

You can select:

- Single-click to open files and folders

or

- Double-click to open files and folders (single click to select)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the "Tap-to-click" option is not appearing in

> KDE System Settings -> Input Devices -> Touchpad

you can disable tap-to-click using the following method:

1. Open a terminal, and install Synaptic using the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install synaptic
   ```
2. Then run the following command:

   ```
   sudo synclient MaxTapTime=0
   ```

This should disable Tap-to-click.
**Note:** if this doesn't work, try running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

...and then follow step 2 again.
This answer was inspired by https://superuser.com/questions/70661/disable-tap-to-click-in-xubuntu.